# Parse Accept Header

Tags: asp.net, regex, http, http-headers

Does anyone have any suggestions (or a regular expression) for parsing the HTTP Accept header?

I am trying to do some content-type negotiation in ASP.NET MVC. There doesn't seem to be a built in way (which is fine, because there are a lot of schools of thought here), but the parsing is not entirely trivial and I would rather not re-invent the wheel if someone has already done it well and is willing to share.

Comment: Good question - I'm looking for this in another project, as well!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you seen [this article](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2005/06/08/restful.html)? It gives a pretty comprehensive implementation for parsing the Accept header and subsequently doing something useful with it.

Comment: There is now a builtin method to retrieve common headers from HttpRequest: `GetTypeHeaders()`, like stated above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75856975/244916

Answer (score 7):

As of .NET 4.5 (I think—Microsoft have made info on framework versions < 4.5 rather obscure these days), you can use [one of the the built in parsers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.mediatypewithqualityheadervalue?view=netframework-4.5) from `System.Net.Http.Headers`:

```
public IOrderedEnumerable<MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue> GetMediaTypes(string headerValue) =>
    headerValue?.Split(',')
        .Select(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse)
        .OrderByDescending(mt => mt.Quality.GetValueOrDefault(1));
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
var headerValue = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";
var mediaTypes = GetMediaTypes(headerValue);
```

Giving you a nice list of all the media types, where the *preferred* option is the first item. Here's a LINQPad `Dump` of the `mediaTypes` result from the example:

[image: LINQPad dump of results]

Hat tip to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927871/need-an-example-on-how-to-get-preferred-language-from-accept-language-request-he#27585837), for getting me on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

I've [written a parser](http://jrgns.net/parse_http_accept_header) in PHP. It's not complex, but it will give you an array of mime types in order of preference.

Comment: the linked site is "disabled"

Answer (score 2):

### ASP.NET Core solution:

I know this is an old question but for anyone using ASP.NET Core who might stumble into it like me, note that you can use the `GetTypedHeaders` extension method on the `Request` (or `Response`) object to get strongly-typed header information, including for `Accept`:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

var accept = Request.GetTypedHeaders().Accept; // `Request` must be an `HttpRequest` instance
accept[0].MediaType
accept[0].Quality
// And so on...
```

Answer (score 1):

Found another implementation in php [here](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/use-accept-language-header)

Answer (score 1):

After reading the xml.com article I decided to not write a function for the Accept header myself ;)

Fortunately the article points to a good library: https://code.google.com/p/mimeparse/ - in my case I need it as a Node.js module: https://github.com/kriskowal/mimeparse

Answer (score 1):

Building on https://stackoverflow.com/a/49011308/275501 from https://stackoverflow.com/users/43140/mark-bell above:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/test")]
    public ActionResult Index() {

        // does this request accept HTML?
        var acceptsHTML = IsAcceptable("text/html");
        var model = FetchViewModel();
        return acceptsHTML ? (ActionResult) View(model) : Ok(model);

    }

    private bool IsAcceptable(string mediaType) =>
        Request.Headers["Accept"].Any(headerValue =>
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headerValue) &&
            headerValue.Split(",").Any(segment => MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(segment).MediaType == mediaType));

    private object FetchViewModel() {

        return new { Description = "To be completed" };

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) is quite complex. If the regex where to follow these rules to the letter, it would become several lines long.

If you already have the Accept-header, and ignore the quotes and the parameters, you could do something like this to match each pair:

```
/([^()<>@,;:\\"\/[\]?={} \t]+)\/([^()<>@,;:\\"\/[\]?={} \t]+)/
```

`*` is included in the character class, so it does not need any special case in the regex.