# Need an example on how to get preferred language from Accept-Language request header

Tags: c#, java, php, .net

I need a code example or library which would parse `Accept-Language` header and return me preferred language. 
[RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) states that:

> The Accept-Language request-header field is similar to Accept, but
>   restricts the set of natural languages that are preferred as a
>   response to the request. Language tags are defined in section 3.10.
>
> ```
>    Accept-Language = "Accept-Language" ":"
>                      1#( language-range [ ";" "q" "=" qvalue ] )
>    language-range  = ( ( 1*8ALPHA *( "-" 1*8ALPHA ) ) | "*" )
> ```
>
> Each language-range MAY be given an associated quality value which
>   represents an estimate of the user's preference for the languages
>   specified by that range. The quality value defaults to "q=1".

Further reading shows that there are too many "optional", "should", "may" and other turns of speech that prevent me from reinventing the wheel - all I want to know is what language user prefers, any browser answers this question billion times a day.

Any code snippet in any language (except Lisp and Assembler please) would be helpful.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Huh! Got something against Lisp? :)

Comment: Split by comma (and preceding space if available), then interrogate each token. Language is the first part, then (if present) a q-code (preference priority). Finally, sort by q values (my understanding is those without a q are to be understood as "1").

Comment: @Anton, i'm bad at counting parentheses :)

Comment: @Brad, that's what I'm trying to avoid, but definitely will start doing it if there'll be no ready answers.

Comment: Who writes web apps in assembler ? :-)

Comment: If you're looking for an updated answer for ASP.NET Core, scroll down some :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, its in PHP but using the same regex i'm sure its adaptable to any language :

```
$langs = array(); // used to store values

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
    // break up string into pieces (languages and q factors)
    preg_match_all('/([a-z]{1,8}(-[a-z]{1,8})?)\s*(;\s*q\s*=\s*(1|0\.[0-9]+))?/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], $lang_parse);

    if (count($lang_parse[1])) {
        // create a list like "en" => 0.8
        $langs = array_combine($lang_parse[1], $lang_parse[4]);

        // set default to 1 for any without q factor
        foreach ($langs as $lang => $val) {
            if ($val === '') $langs[$lang] = 1;
        }

        // sort list based on value 
        arsort($langs, SORT_NUMERIC);
    }
}
```

produces a sorted array with preferred language first :

```
Array
(
    [en-ca] => 1
    [en] => 0.8
    [en-us] => 0.6
    [de-de] => 0.4
    [de] => 0.2
)
```

From example `ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` header : `en-ca,en;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.6,de-de;q=0.4,de;q=0.2`

[Working example here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0GnCpC)

Comment: Thanks, you're just in time - I was goggling at my stub method always returning "en" ))

Answer (score 47):

**Solution:**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string header = "en-ca,en;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.6,de-de;q=0.4,de;q=0.2";
            var languages = header.Split(',')
                .Select(StringWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse)
                .OrderByDescending(s => s.Quality.GetValueOrDefault(1));
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @weston : what kind of magic this is: .Select(StringWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse) ?

Comment: Lol, called a method group http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Update for ASP.NET Core:

Microsoft has that built in by now.
Use the `AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider`:

```cs
IApplicationBuilder builder = ...;
builder.UseRequestLocalization(options => options
  .AddInitialRequestCultureProvider(new AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider()));
```

you can then get the `IRequestCultureFeature` through the context:

```cs
// probably injected through your DI container
IHttpContextAccessor _accessor = ...;
await _accessor.HttpContext.Features
  .Get<IRequestCultureFeature>().Provider
  .DetermineProviderCultureResult(_accessor.HttpContext);
```

that returns a `ProviderCultureResult?`, you can then read the cultures (in form of `IList<StringSegment>`) from that.