# Web Api - Localization Property value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

sModel:

```
public class Product
{
    public string NameEN { get; set; }
    public string NameFR { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Controller :

```
    // GET: api/Products/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
    {
        return Ok(new Product(){NameEN = "Cookie", NameFR = "Biscuit", Price = 10});
    }
```

I want this result :

```
{"Name" = "Cookie", "Price" = "10"}
```

The produtcs are store in a database

How can I transform my properties NameEN and NameFR to Name during the serialization with the desired Accept-Language?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and access culture specific strings using a resource file.

First create a resource file and name it according to the culture code.  So for the default you'll have `Names.resx` and for french you'll have `Names.fr-FR.resx`.  From here you should open up the properties of each resx file and give it a similar custom tool namespace such as `ViewRes`.  Now when you access the resx file to grab a string like so: `ViewRes.Names.MyString` you'll get the string according to the current culture defined in `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` which you can set.  You can set this using the accept-language in your Global.asax.cs file like so:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string culture = HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables.Get("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE");
    CultureInfo ci = culture as CultureInfo;
    if (ci == null)
        ci = new CultureInfo("en");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
}
```

Now the next time you access `ViewRes.Names` in your controller it will be with the culture set by accept-language.

You can also set the culture when accessing your resx strings like so:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id, string culture)
{
    ViewRes.Names.Culture = new CultureInfo(culture);
    return Ok(new Product(){Name = ViewRes.Names.MyString, Price = 10});
}
```

Comment: It can not work because the products are store in a database.

Example of product :
    1.  Cookie, Biscuit, 1.99$
    2.  Car, Automobile, 4999$


My product are dynamic. I can't use resx for storing my value.

Comment: @jonlabr you'll need to apply you own logic then.  Capture and parse the accept-language value and present the name value accordingly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927871/need-an-example-on-how-to-get-preferred-language-from-accept-language-request-he

Comment: I can't believe this feature is not include :( Thank you!